# Why can't I catch this exception from a constructor?

Tags: c#, exception, reflection

In this test code, why does the test fail with an `ArgumentNullException`, despite that it is handled?

```cs
        [Test]
        public void ExceptionBehaviorTest()
        {
            // This works. An instance is returned
            var testInstance = (TestClass)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TestClass), "Hello World");
            Assert.NotNull(testInstance);

            // This passes. Exception is generated and caught
            Assert.Throws<ArgumentNullException>(() => new TestClass(null));

            try
            {
                // This throws ArgumentNullException but the catch handler is not invoked. This fails the test
                testInstance = (TestClass)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TestClass), (string)null);
                Assert.Fail("Should not get here");
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException)
            {
            }
        }

        private sealed class TestClass
        {
            public TestClass(string arg)
            {
                Argument = arg ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(arg));
            }

            public string Argument
            {
                get;
            }
        }
```

If I run the code in the debugger, it stops in the `TestClass` ctor, saying that the exception is not handled. But the calling function is visible in the stack, so the problem is not related to some part being executed on a different thread.

[Background: In my real-world code, I'm iterating over a bunch of classes and testing whether they have a ctor with a specific argument. This is to prevent runtime errors later, as the classes are constructed using dependency injection.]

Comment: Instead of `testInstance = (TestClass)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TestClass), (string)null)` it should be `testInstance = (TestClass)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TestClass), new object[] { null })`.

Comment: That would work, too. The signature of the overload that's used here is `public static object? CreateInstance (Type type, params object?[]? args)`, so explicity wrapping in an object array is not necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=net-5.0#System_Activator_CreateInstance_System_Type_System_Object___)

> **TargetInvocationException**
>
> The constructor being called throws an
> exception.

So you need to catch `TargetInvocationException` in this situation, also if you like you can use `when` though I am not sure it helps with your test much

```
catch (TargetInvocationException ex) when (ex.InnerException is ArgumentNullException)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Caught");
}
```

Comment: Yes, I found this same solution while you were typing. Thanks anyway. (I was initially expecting that exception type only for internal errors, such as when the constructor is not found)